# Max function is not filtering results

Tags: sql

I am trying to only get the most recent start date based on the last updated date field. When I try to use max, it is not filtering the results to only the most recent data.

```
select max(a.LAST_UPDATED_DATE),a.term_start  
from table AS a
where a.ID='123456' and location='Colorado' 
group by 2
```

This is the output I am getting

| MAX(a.LAST_UPDATED_DATE) | TERM_START |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-27T18:27:50Z | 2023-04-12T07:00:00Z |
| 2023-01-24T18:26:44Z | 2023-04-05T07:00:00Z |

I only want to get

| MAX(a.LAST_UPDATED_DATE) | TERM_START |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-27T18:27:50Z | 2023-04-12T07:00:00Z |

Comment: Does the other record has `ID='123456'` and `location='Colorado'`?  If yes, then there is nothing wrong with the result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast response. Yes, the other record does have the same ID and location. What can I do to only pull the most recent last updated date, regardless if there are older records for the same ID and location?

Comment: Remove the `TERM_START` column.

Comment: @Eric I need that column though. NO other way?

Comment: Order by last_update_date desc limit 1 (or  however you neex to restrict the number of returned rows.

Comment: @Shadow thank you so much, that did it!! Can't believe i didnt think about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this on Oracle, MS Server, and HANA:

```
    Select
    *
    from
    (
    select 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a.ID, a.location
         ORDER BY term_start DESC, a.LAST_UPDATED_DATE DESC
     ) row_num,
     a.LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
     a.term_start  
    from  a
    where a.ID='123456' and 
    location='Colorado'
    ) as test
    where row_num = 1
```

It will still work if you remove `where a.ID='123456' and location='Colorado' and you will see all of the locations and ids in your result

Using each a.ID and location combination in the partition where row_num = 1 returns the most recent value since within the partition the values are ordered term_start DESC, a.LAST_UPDATED_DATED_DATE DESC.

In your code, you are grouping on the term_start which results in unique values for TERM_START, therefore, two rows.  You might want to group on the a.ID and location instead.  You will get the MAX (a.LAST_UPDATED) per location.  In the intent of the query you also mentioned you wanted most recent.  The MAX and Most recent are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @greybeard, "PARTITION BY a.ID, a.location"  in the code above groups or partitions the row number for those combinations.  All ID and Location combinations will have their own.  I used this solution in case you were interested in more than one ID  and location in one query.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to window function, you can use it

```
select max(a.LAST_UPDATED_DATE) partition by (a.ID, location) ,a.term_start  
from table AS a
where a.ID='123456' and location='Colorado'
```